# Uploading images from server using Php

Tags: php, image, upload

In my php application i have a folder in which all the photos are kept.

The images are in different sizes.So i want to select photos from the folder and applying some image functions and upload to a different folder through php code.

This is same as image uploading but the difference is that the source file is in server

That is i want to select photos from server applying some image functions and upload again on the server
Pls help me

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep them on the same server, no further uploading is necessary. You can just perform whatever manipulations you want (resize, etc.) then use PHP's filesystem libraries to move the files around on the server. Check them out [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

Comment: true, but what's up if the server is external?

Comment: From what I gathered from the question, it's the same server.

Comment: true, +1 for you then, my fault sorry

Answer (score 0):

maybe with curl http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html here a tip explaining how to send data with curl

Answer (score 0):

If you select a photo from the folder and applied some image functions, instead of saving the file back to the original file, you could simply save it to it's new location...

In that case you don't need uploading and/or moving...